# Define article owner ( Couldn't find Article without an ID)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to define an article owner, for that I have to independent resources, which are not nested in each other (user, article).

Each article has an user_id attribute which corresponds to the id of the user who created the article.

Now I'm trying to match both so I can create an article owner.

This is how I'm trying to do it:

Articles_controller.rb

```
def show
      @article = Article.find(params[:id])
      @user_id = Article.find(params[:user_id])
      @user= User.find_by(id: user_id)
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your action should be like:

```
def show
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  @user= User.find(params[:user_id])
end
```

You are trying to fetch an `article` using the `id` of `user` and that `id` article doesn't exist in database that is why it is causing error.

And the best practice is that instead of fetching the `user` in `@user` variable you should use `@article.user`in the `view` or anywhere else. Means you should fetch it from the association itself.